# Get width of text in span with text-overflow: ellipsis; at IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a span which is in a div with text-overflow set:

```html
<div id="parent" style="width: 50px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
  <span id="child">exampleasdaadasdsfdgs</span>
</div>
```

When I try to get the width of the text in the span, I tried:

```css
$("#child").width();
```

In most browsers it works, but in IE 11 (perhaps in more) it doesn't.
When I delete "text-overflow: ellipsis;" it shows the correct length of the text.

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyqr5zm9/1/) for testing.

Is there a good (and not to slow) method for getting the width with IE11, except from getting the length of the text and multiply it with the font-size?

Comment: getting the length of the text and multiply it with the font-size will work only if you use monospace font

Comment: That's a bug in IE, but for this particular case, you can read the parent's `scrollWidth` value, it will output the width of its content (i.e. of your span). https://jsfiddle.net/em9jap8f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution I use now, is to remove the style {text-overflow: ellipsis;} and add it after the measurement again.

```
$("#parent").css("text-overflow", "clip");
$('#childwidth').html($("#child").width());
$("#parent").css("text-overflow", "ellipsis");
```

For me this is at the moment the best solution (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyqr5zm9/4/)).
I have a relativ complex layout, which much relativ lengths and it would take more time to reproduce this layout.

Answer (score 2):

If you know **font size** and **font family**, you can use canvas measureText() to get text width

```
function textWidth(text, font) {
 font = font || "16px Arial"
 var c = document.createElement('canvas');
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.font = font;
 return ctx.measureText(text).width;
}

var myText = $('#mySpan').html();
console.log(textWidth(myText))
```

Remember that it only works if you know the font size and font family before hand.

Comment: Considering you should be able to get the font info from the stylesheet, that's quite a cunning solution.

Comment: If there is no other solution, I will do it this way. But I'm searching for a nicer, more elegant solution.

Comment: At the moment I have your solution and removing the text-overflow and at it after the width measure (https://jsfiddle.net/xyqr5zm9/4/). But I don't like both of this ideas that much.

Comment: Why don't you create an invisible element (opacity:0), measure it, then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This is another answer that i came up with, though it might not work at times, span get display block style and padding from parent for example. Position can also be absolute.
This works by creating new element, append it to a parent or body, measure its width then delete it.

```
function textWidth(text, parent) {
     var textElement = $('<span style="opacity:0; position: fixed; overflow: visible" class="it_has_similar_style_as_the_one_we_need_to_measure">' + text + '</span>');
     //if you have a parent element, append it here so it can inherit some necessary styles
     if(!parent) {
        $(document.body).append(textElement);
     } else {
        parent.append(textElement);
     }
     var width = textElement.width();
     textElement.remove();
     return width;
}
```